# testng task not running with ant

Tags: ant, testng

Using ant to run testng tests but it does not run or show any error. even the message(Running Tests) is not printed in the console. here is the build.xml. build happens successfully and creates a JAR though. appreciate any help on this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="BANC">

<property name="project.path" value="." />
<property name="src" value="${project.path}/src" />
<property name="bin" value="${project.path}/bin" />
<property name="testngxmldir" value="${project.path}/src/com/portico/regressionsuite" />
<property name="bancJarFile.path" value="./build/BANC.jar" />

<!-- Set class path libraries to be used for compilation -->
<path id="class.path">
<pathelement location="lib" path="lib/activation.jar"/>
<pathelement location="lib" path="lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar"/>
<pathelement location="lib" path="lib/jxl.jar"/>
<pathelement location="lib" path="lib/logging-selenium-1.2.jar"/>
<pathelement location="lib" path="lib/mail.jar"/>
<pathelement location="lib" path="lib/ojdbc14.jar"/>
<pathelement location="lib" path="lib/poi-3.0.2-FINAL.jar"/>
<pathelement location="lib" path="lib/reportng-1.1.1.jar"/>
<pathelement location="lib" path="lib/saxon-8.7.jar"/>
<pathelement location="lib" path="lib/selenium-grid-demo-1.0.7.jar"/>
<pathelement location="lib" path="lib/selenium-grid-demo-standalone-1.0.7.jar"/>
<pathelement location="lib" path="lib/selenium-grid-hub-1.0.7.jar"/>
<pathelement location="lib" path="lib/selenium-grid-hub-standalone-1.0.7.jar"/>
<pathelement location="lib" path="lib/selenium-grid-remote-control-1.0.7.jar"/>
<pathelement location="lib" path="lib/selenium-grid-remote-control-standalone-1.0.7.jar"/>
<pathelement location="lib" path="lib/selenium-grid-tools-1.0.7.jar"/>
<pathelement location="lib" path="lib/selenium-grid-tools-standalone-1.0.7.jar"/>
<pathelement location="lib" path="lib/selenium-server-1.0.3-standalone.jar"/>
<pathelement location="lib" path="lib/velocity-1.7.jar"/>
<pathelement location="lib" path="lib/jna-3.4.0.jar"/>
<pathelement location="lib" path="lib/sikuli-script.jar"/>
<pathelement location="lib" path="lib/testng-6.8.jar"/>
<pathelement location="lib" path="${bin}"/>
</path>

<!-- Compile targets-->
<target name="banc">
    <echo message="Compiling BANC Source..." />
    <mkdir dir="${bin}" />
    <javac classpathref="class.path" destdir="${bin}" encoding="UTF-8" optimize="off" 
    debug="on" failonerror="true" srcdir="${src}" />
    <jar destfile="${bancJarFile.path}" basedir="${bin}" />
</target>

<taskdef name="testng" classname="org.testng.TestNGAntTask">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="lib/testng-6.8.jar"/>
    </classpath>
</taskdef>

<target name="runTest">
<echo message="Running Tests..." />
    <testng classpathref="class.path" outputDir="${project.path}/test-output" 
    sourcedir="${bin}" haltOnfailure="true">
        <xmlfileset dir="${testngxmldir}" includes="regressionsuite.xml"/>
    </testng>   
</target>

 </project>
```

Comment: How do you run ant? The ant file has neither a root element with default task nor any dependencies between tasks.

Comment: that is just a typo(it is corrected now). i was doing a sample run thats why havent included any dependencies. I have tried running ant from eclipse and command line but same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it appears you don't tell ant which of the targets to run -- so it simply picks the first one. If you run it with `ant banc runTest` it shoudl work fine.

The usual way to do this is to define an empty target that depends on all desired targets aud set that as default in the `<project>` tag. Furthermore your "runTest" target should depend on "banc", since running the tests requires that the project has been built beforehand. In that case you can also simply do an `ant runTest` -- ant will automatically run all dependent tasks in proper order.

Comment: Thanks. "ant banc runTest" worked. Most of the online documentation do not really mention that a task needs to specified if there no dependencies between them.